# random forest: how to favor false negatives over false positives

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to tackle a binary classification problem with some custom random forest implementation.

The goal is to predict the likelihood that the item belongs to class A.  The evaluation strategy is defined such that false positives (a high likelihood for A while the actual class is B) are punished harder than false negatives (a low likelihood for A while the actual class is A).

How should the standard algorithm be adapted to take advantage of this to get a higher evaluation score?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try using the package rfUtilities: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rfUtilities/rfUtilities.pdf

It was designed to deal with class imbalance by predicting the liklihood of occurence for a single category.